# Sharepoint login

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointfoundation2010, sharepoint-security, sharepointadmin

how can I let non-domain users username/password login my sharepoint site (is on internet)? I am using Sharepoint 2010 foundation.  can I authentic them via Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue to use Active Directory, you will need to give an AD account to these users. Otherwise, SharePoint also supports Forms Based Authentication and SAML token-based authentication.

Note that these authentication methods are not mutually exclusive. You can use any combination of authentication methods supported by the authentication mode of the Web Application (SAML token-based authentication is only supported when your Web Application is in Claims Based mode).

For more information, see [Plan authentication methods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form Base Authentication.

Reference: http://blog.morg.nl/2011/08/step-by-step-forms-based-authentication-fba-on-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: link based answers are very bad, please extract some essential part of it and leave link as external information

Comment: because it is step by step to configure FBA for SharePoint

Comment: so what? after some time, this sever may goes down, and your answer is nothing for people searching for a good answer